# Fire an event inside vscode extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a `vscode` extension. Inside that I want to select part of text and change the color of selected text. So whenever part of code is selected the font color is red.

For doing this I need fire event inside `vscode extention`.

How can I do that? 1. Fire an event inside `vscode extention` whenever part of code selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Which event do you want to fire? Just define a Text Decorator for the selected range.

Comment: Could you please put a code sample here?